# VueJS - child component not updating with prop set from parent computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to pass the value of a computed method which changes, into my child component, with little success.  I'm making a button component which has several different save states - yet my button is always stuck on one and doesn't update with the parent.

Parent

```
  computed: {
    isSaving() {
      return (
  this.$_.values(this.$store.getters["CommonSettings/saving"]).filter(
          status => status && status != "done"
        ).length > 0
      );
    }


 <SaveButton v-bind:saveState="isSaving"/>
```

Child

```
<script>    
export default {
  name: "saveButton",
  props: ['saveState']
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="settings--button-wrapper">
    <button class="btn btn--small" type="button" @click="submit()" v-if="!saveState">
      <svg v-if="!saveState">
        <use xlink:href="/img/sprite.svg#transparent-tick" />
      </svg>
      <span v-if="!saveState">Save changes</span>
    </button>
    <spinner v-if="saveState" class="settings--spinner">
      <span>Saving...</span>
    </spinner>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I put my SaveButton component **template** directly into the parent, it works perfectly.  When I extract it into its own component like above, it's stuck on "Saving..." and doesn't change.

When I try the below in the parent:-

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class="settings--button-wrapper">
    <button class="btn btn--small" type="button" @click="submit()" v-if="!saveState">
      <svg v-if="!saveState">
        <use xlink:href="/img/sprite.svg#transparent-tick" />
      </svg>
      <span v-if="!saveState">Save changes</span>
    </button>
    <spinner v-if="saveState" class="settings--spinner">
      <span>Saving...</span>
    </spinner>
  </div>
     <SaveButton v-bind:saveState="isSaving"/>
</div>
</template>
```

..the button component also affects the original button code above it - so both are broken.  When I remove the SaveButton component, the original code works again.

When I inspect the above in my Vue inspector, the `isSaving` variable is stuck on true.  I think it's perhaps the original value at start up, but I'm unsure how it's getting stuck like this.  **Somehow** - my child component seems to be affecting the value of the parents computed isSaving property - as it gets stuck on `true` on page load.

Comment: in the last piece of code <template> can only have 1 direct child, so put your SaveButton inside div to say the least.

Comment: @curveball - that was a copy/paste error - sorry.  Fixed it now - that isn't the cause of my issue.

Comment: I think we need a reproducible example. Maybe there are missing imports etc. Could you extract the code in question and make it as a sandbox example? PS. Where is it always stuck on true? Maybe the data filtered in isSaving is always true indeed?

Comment: Just to clarify, the value of `isSaving` is updating in your parent component, just not getting passed down to your child component?

Comment: @Hannah - I'm refactoring things out into their own components.  When I try to put this button into it's own component - it no longer gets the updates from the parent - it is stuck on the initial value.

When I inspect the components in my browser on load - the parent "isSaving" is set to true, and the child is also set to true.  When I remove the component and revert to the original code, "isSaving" updates to false immediately, as it should.

So my component is somehow affecting the value of the computed property in the parent.

Comment: Could you add the relevant part of your store, including the `CommonSettings/saving` getter and any associated state?

Comment: I think I know what's going on.  So the values returned from my store are different when I use the component in my page, and when I don't.  It basically returns an array of items, one of which is "requested" - so I'm guessing it's tracking if the page has requested data perhaps..

So - it seems like there is a slight timing issue when I add the component, perhaps the data doesn't have enough time to update.  So - is there a way to delay my child component from rendering until my page is fully loaded?

Comment: I can probably just lean on `mounted` to check this.  Still a bit weird that this is happening though.

Comment: @Hannah the issue turned out to be my button submit function.  `:handleSubmit="submit()"` - so submit was being called when the component mounted.  I had to call it without the () parenthesis....  

Not something I would have expected to happen..